# How to get nested json objects using react js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs

I'm using laravel, and im trying to check to see if a user is following a user, if so the text box will change from follow to following.

I can get the id of the user easily but i can't check to see if a user has followable id

[image]

I need to reference the pivot object, and this object only shows when i do

`<div id="profile" data='{{ $myuser->followers}}'></div>`

but i need to use `$myuser` variable by itself.

This is what i have so far.

**Profile.blade.php**

```
  <div id="profile" data='{{ $myuser}}'></div>
```

**Profile.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let id = JSON.parse(this.props.data);
        // console.log('data from component', JSON.parse(this.props.data));
        this.state = {
            btnText: 'Follow',
            className: 'follow-button',
            user:{
                // i can get a user id, but i cant get the followable id.
                id:id.id, 
                followers:id.pivot.followable_id
            }
        };
    }

    myfollow(user) {
        axios('/user/follow/'+ this.state.user.id , { method: "POST" })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
          });
    };

    componentDidMount(){

        console.log('data from component', this.state.user.followers);

        // if (this.state.user.followers === 3){    
        //  this.setState({
        //         btnText:'Following', 
        //         className:'following-button'
        //     });
        // }
    }
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function getProfile($user)
{  
    $users = User::with(['posts.likes' => function($query) {
                        $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                        $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                    }, 'follow','follow.follower'])
                  ->where('name','=', $user)->get();

    $user = $users->map(function(User $myuser){


        $myuser['followedByMe'] = $myuser->follow->count() == 0 ? false : true;

        return $myuser;

    });



    if(!$user){
        return redirect('404');
    }

    return view ('profile')->with('user', $user);
}
```

**MyFollow.php** (model)

```
public function followedByMe()
{
    foreach($this->follower as $followers) {
        if ($followers->user_id == auth()->id()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**User.php Model**

```
?php

namespace App;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use App\GalleryImage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\MyFollow;
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanFollow;
use Overtrue\LaravelFollow\Traits\CanBeFollowed;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,CanFollow, CanBeFollowed;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);

    }


    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(GalleryImage::class, 'user_id');

    }


    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }

    public function follow()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
    }


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }




}
```

Comment: what is your db structure and the models files

Comment: i don't understand what you're referencing ?

Comment: how is the relationship between a user and another is established, is it polymorphic or many to many

Comment: `public function follow()
    {   
        return $this->hasMany('App\MyFollow');
    }
`

Comment: does that help ?

Comment: nope i need to see the models files, the user specifically

Comment: I updated the post, sorry for the delay

Comment: ok you need to better structure your relationships, so if a user can follow for ex a post and another user, have a polymorphic, if only another user, have many to many, and btw once you have that user you shouldn't have a problem with getting its followers, and loop through them, and you are getting the pivot table only when you call `$user->followers()` because this what supposed to happen, check the relationships docs

Comment: How would i fix this though, or whats the best way to get the nested objects in the privot array. I can get the normal objects like name, id etc. but not the nested object.

Comment: `User::with('followers')` is what you need, and check in the js for a certain user

Comment: but as i can see from your User.php that relationship is not defined

Comment: let me give it a go because i think its already defined. this here defines it `, 'follow','follow.follower'])`